# compose function and functional module

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, python-3.x, function-composition

[Python 3.2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.2/howto/functional.html#the-functional-module) refers to [Collin Winter's `functional` module](http://oakwinter.com/code/functional/) which contains function `compose`:

> The compose() function implements function composition. In other
>   words, it returns a wrapper around the outer and inner callables, such
>   that the return value from inner is fed directly to outer.

Unfortunately, this module hasn't been updated since July 2006; I wonder if there's any replacement available.

For now, I only need `compose` function. Is the following original `functional.compose` definition still good for Python 3?

```
def compose(func_1, func_2, unpack=False):
    """
    compose(func_1, func_2, unpack=False) -> function

    The function returned by compose is a composition of func_1 and func_2.
    That is, compose(func_1, func_2)(5) == func_1(func_2(5))
    """
    if not callable(func_1):
        raise TypeError("First argument to compose must be callable")
    if not callable(func_2):
        raise TypeError("Second argument to compose must be callable")

    if unpack:
        def composition(*args, **kwargs):
            return func_1(*func_2(*args, **kwargs))
    else:
        def composition(*args, **kwargs):
            return func_1(func_2(*args, **kwargs))
    return composition
```

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281693/is-it-a-good-idea-to-have-a-syntax-sugar-to-function-composition-in-python) is somewhat related; it asks whether Python should support special syntax for `compose`.

Comment: Python 3 does ot have the  `callable`  built in keyword - it is usually replaced with `hasattr(obj, "__call__") ` otherwise, the code above should work.

Comment: `callable()` was added back to the language in 3.2.

Comment: I think that should be fine in Python 3.2. As others point out, for Python 3.0 and 3.1, you'd need to implement `callable`, but if you're happy with 3.2, just copy, paste and credit.

Comment: Thanks.. Then the only remaining question is whether `functional` module has a replacement in Python 3.

Comment: Since I couldn't find a port of `functional` to Py3, I slapped one together at [github](https://github.com/abarnert/functional). But I ran into a problem with the copyright/license stuff that stalled me. I think it might be easier to reimplement it from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation of `compose` is valid for python 3.2 as discussed in the comments above.
Most of the functions of the library you gave have a python equivalent written in the [documentation](http://oakwinter.com/code/functional/documentation/index.html).

Functions such as `map` and `filter` are already implemented in python and can also be simply expressed as list comprehensions. Python has an `id` function returning the identity of an object (as integer), but the `id` function of the library can be expressed as `lambda x: x`.

Another modules you might find interesting are `itertools` and `functools` which has `partial` and `reduce` (which is similar to `foldl` but the argument order is not the same).

Here is a simple implementations of a few of them that I didn't find in the standard library:

```
from functools import reduce

def flip(f):
    if not callable(f):
        raise TypeError("Cannot filp a non-callable object")
    def result(*args, **kw):
        args = list(args)
        args.reverse()
        return f(*args, **kw)
    return result

def ilast(i):
    return reduce(lambda _, x: x, i)

def iscanl(f, v, seq):
    yield v
    for a in seq:
        v = f(v, a)
        yield v

def scanl(*args, **kw):
    return list(iscanl(*args, **kw))

def foldl(*args, **kw):
    return ilast(iscanl(*args, **kw))
# Or using reduce
#def foldl(f, v, seq):
#    return reduce(f, seq, v)

def iscanr_reverse(f, v, seq):
    return iscanl(flip(f), v, seq)

def scanr(*args, **kw):
    result = list(iscanr_reverse(*args, **kw))
    result.reverse()
    return result

def foldr(*args, **kw):
    return ilast(iscanr_reverse(*args, **kw))
```