# Compressing "n"-time object member call

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda, beautifulsoup

Is there any non-explicit `for` way to call a member `n` times upon an object?

I was thinking about some `map/reduce/lambda` approach, but I couldn't figure out a way to do this -- if it's possible.

Just to add context, I'm using `BeautifulSoup`, and I'm extracting some elements from an html table; I extract some elements, and then, the last one.

Since I have:

```
# First value
print value.text

# Second value
value = value.nextSibling
print value.text

# Ninth value
for i in xrange(1, 7):
    value = value.nextSibling
print value.text
```

I was wondering if there's any `lambda` approach -- or something else -- that would allow me to do this:

```
# Ninth value
((value = value.nextSibling) for i in xrange(1, 7))
print value.text
```

P.S.: No, there's no problem whatsoever with the `for` approach, except I really enjoy one-liner solutions, and this would fit really nice in my code.

Comment: What does `nextSibling` return in the case there is no next sibling?

Comment: @sr2222 you can consider `nextSibling` is always to return a valid value; the issue I'm trying to point rather about the code writing -- working is a mere consequence (:

Comment: So this isn't a "handle n-length list" problem, it's a "one-liner for specific slice" question.

Comment: @sr2222 I hope the title edit suits better the problem itself. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a strong preference for the loop, but you *could* use `reduce`:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...        self.count = 0
...     def callme(self):
...        self.count += 1
...        return self
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x.callme(),range(7),a)
<__main__.Foo object at 0xec390>
>>> a.count
7
```

Comment: whoa, looks very neat; let me try it!

Comment: @StoryTeller -- I'm happy to see alternatives to satisfy OP's criteria.  As I state up front, I wouldn't use this.  I'd use a loop.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The OP explicitly said he wants a one-liner, even though he knows it isn't idiomatic. So it's a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: Wouldn't using map be easier? As in `map(lambda _: a.callme(), range(7))`

Comment: @l4mpi: No, that will return a list of 7 copies of `a.callme()`, not `a.callme().callme()…callme()`.

Comment: @l4mpi -- Nope.  That calls the `callme` method on the same object 7 times -- It was just easist to have my method return `self` so it could chain an infinite number of `.callme().callme().callme()...`

Comment: Ah, of course... I overlooked the fact that the returned object was used for successive calls as it doesn't make a difference in this example.

Comment: Yes well, my point is that it isn't really a *one-liner*. You have to write quite a few lines of preperation. If it's for a single use, I stand by what I said.

Comment: @StoryTeller: What lines of preparation? He's just created a simple example to test his one-liner with.

Comment: @StoryTeller the actual solution is just the `reduce` line, everything else is just an example.

Comment: Never read code examples before youv'e had coffee. My apologies @mgilson

Comment: Well, among all the very amazing answers, I'm accepting yours, as I'm some what lambdaddicted (: Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 4):

You want a one-liner equivalent of this:

```
for i in xrange(1, 7):
    value = value.nextSibling
```

This is one line:

```
for i in xrange(1, 7): value = value.nextSibling
```

If you're looking for something more functional, what you really want is a [`compose`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977612/compose-function-and-functional-module) function, so you can compose `callme()` (or `attrgetter('my_prop')`, or whatever) 7 times.

Comment: geez, man! didn't know I could do that (: let me try this one too!

Comment: As a side note -- You cheated ;-).

Comment: @mgilson: There is no cheating in code golf. (And I upvoted your comment so you'll get a higher score, which counts as losing in golf, right?)

Answer (score 2):

In case of `BS` you can use `nextSiblingGenerator()` with `itertools.islice` to get the nth sibling. It would also handle situations where there is no nth element.

```
from itertools import islice

nth = 7
next(islice(elem.nextSiblingGenerator(), nth, None), None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: `eval` is evil.

```
value = eval('value' + ('.nextSibling' * 7))
```

Comment: yep, that's amazingly evil (:

Answer (score 1):

Ah! But `reduce` is not available in Python3, at least not as a built in.

So here is my try, portable to Python2/3 and based on the OP failed attempt:

```
[globals().update(value=value.nextSibling) for i in range(7)]
```

That assumes that `value` is a global variable. If value happens to be a member variable, then write instead:

```
[self.__dict__.update(value=value.nextSibling) for i in range(7)]
```

You cannot use `locals()` because the list comprehension creates a nested local scope, so the real `locals()` is not directly available. However, you can capture it with a bit of work:

```
(lambda loc : [loc.update(x=x.nextSibling) for i in range(7)])(locals())
```

Or easier if you don't mind duplicating the number of lines:

```
loc = locals()
[loc.update(value=value.nextSibling) for i in range(7)]
```

Or if you really fancy one-liners:

```
loc = locals() ; [loc.update(value=value.nextSibling) for i in range(7)]
```

Yes, Python can use `;` too 8-)

**UPDATE**:

Another fancy variation, now with `map` instead of the list comprehension:

```
list(map(lambda d : d.update(value=value.nextSibling), 7 * [locals()]))
```

Note the clever use of list multiplication to capture the current `locals()` *and* create the initial iterable at the same time.

Comment: whoa, man! I'll try this one too. And now I'm quite afraid I don't know which answer to choose ^^

Comment: well you can just put `try: from functools import reduce; except: pass` at the top, and then the code is portable with Python 2 and 3

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is `locals` abuse -- especially since it's [**not guaranteed**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) that modifying locals will modify the current namespace (in which case you'd just end up with a list of `None`, and no mutated `value`)

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to write it would be:

```
value = reduce(lambda x, _: x.nextSibling, xrange(1,7), value)
```

Comment: very nice one, too; I guess this is somehow a shortening on the vars from the accepted answer. Just a question: wouldn't `reduce(lambda x, _: x.nextSibling, xrange(1,7), value)` suffice, as the assignment is already performed in the reduce process?

Comment: @Rubens: what do you mean assignment? How would that be possible? Python is pass by value. A function cannot assign to the caller's variables.