# Python: avoid nested loop on array

Tags: python

I am recursing through an xml file, using etree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('x.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root[0]:
 for child in child.getchildren():
        for child in child.getchildren():
            for child in child.getchildren():
               print(child.attrib)
```

what is the idiomatic way in python to avoid these nested for loop.

```
  getchildren() ⇒ list of Element instances [#]
    Returns all subelements. The elements are returned in document order.

Returns:
A list of subelements.
```

I saw some post in SO like, 
[Avoiding nested for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174745/avoiding-nested-for-loops)
but doesn't directly translate to my use.

thanks.

Comment: `itertools.product` is a nice way to avoid nested loops. Why doesn't that translate to your use?

Comment: Do you specifically want attributes for elements 4 children deep?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean itertools.product doesn't suit me, but couldn't translate that example to arrays like in my case. I havn't done much Python, but will try.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the children that are `n` levels deep in the tree, and then iterate through them, you can do:

```
def childrenAtLevel(tree, n):
    if n == 1:
        for child in tree.getchildren():
            yield child
    else:
        for child in tree.getchildren():
            for e in childrenAtLevel(child, n-1):
                yield e
```

Then, to get the elements four levels deep, you would simply say:

```
for e in childrenAtLevel(root, 4):
     # do something with e
```

Or, if you want to get all of the leaf nodes (i.e. the nodes that don't have any children themselves), you can do:

```
def getLeafNodes(tree):
    if len(tree) == 0:
         yield tree
    else:
         for child in tree.getchildren():
            for leaf in getLeafNodes(child):
                yield leaf
```

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.chain.from_iterable` will flatten one level of nesting; you can use `functools.reduce` to apply it *n* times ([Compressing "n"-time object member call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635914/compressing-n-time-object-member-call?lq=1)):

```
from itertools import chain
from functools import reduce

for child in reduce(lambda x, _: chain.from_iterable(x), range(3), root):
    print(child.attrib)
```

Note that `getchildren` is deprecated; iterating a node yields its children directly.