# Avoid nested loop for datetimeindex

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, pandas

I'm trying to code as efficiently and pythonicly as possible (that is avoiding loops whenever possible) and I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462325/python-avoid-nested-for-loop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780567/python-avoid-nested-loop-on-array) but they seem to be irrelevant to my question.

Consider a `pd.DataFrame` called `df` with 30 years of hourly data for 28 countries:

- index: `datetime64[ns]` (e.g. `'1980-01-01 00:00:00'`) and in
- columns: a 2-digit countrycode of each of the 28 countries.

e.g.

```
countrycode                AT        BE        [...]
time                                   
1980-01-01 00:00:00  0.016947  0.059076
1980-01-01 01:00:00  0.019461  0.068575
[...]
2009-31-12 23:00:00  0.119735  0.287495
```

In order to create yearly boxplots for every country separately, e.g. via `ds[country].plot(kind='box')`, I intend to transform this DataFrame into the following form:

- columns: `pd.MultiIndex` such as `(countrycode, year)` e.g. ('AT', 1980), ('AT', 1981), ...
- index: `range(8760)` e.g. (0, 1, ... 8759)

The piece of code I came up with works well, but its damn slow due to a nested loop:

```
years = sorted(set(df.index.year))
ds = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex
                            .from_product([df.columns, years]))
for reg, col in df.iteritems():
    for year, group in col.groupby(by=df.index.year):
        ds.loc[:, (reg, year)] = group.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Any ideas to code this part more efficiently are highly welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['countrycode','year']).size().unstack().plot(kind='box')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work, as neither 'year' (as part of `datetime64[ns]`-index) nor 'countrycode' (as name of the columns) are valid keys.